# Suggestions for a more elegant solution to replacing 1 character in a URL

Tags: php, regex

So, I have a URL I am receiving via an API.
The pattern would be similar to `https://www.example.co.uk/category/000000000k/0000`

I want to replace the second `k` character, with a `x` char.

I tried using `str_replace()` but it also replaces the first `k` character.

So what I did was use `preg_split()`, so my solution is:

```
$url = preg_split( '/[\/]+/', 'https://www.example.co.uk/category/000000000k/0000' );
$url = $url[0] . '//' . $url[1] . '/' . $url[2] . '/' . str_replace( 'k', 'x', $url[3] ) . '/' . $url[4];
```

So, my solution works are long as the URL pattern does not change. However, I think it could be more elegant if my Regex was up to par.

Anyone here could point me to a better path?

Comment: So replacing 0000k with 0000x can't work for some reason?

Comment: @CK With the '0000000k' section, the 0's represent a unique identifier consisting of random digits.

Comment: Check out the answers below then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `k/` always have numbers before that and another part doesn't have same pattern, this may work.

```
$url = "https://www.example.co.uk/category/000000000k/0000";
$url = preg_replace("/([0-9])k\//", "$1x/", $url);
```

Anoter pattern. Find 3rd `/`, make sub string, and replace.

```
$url = "https://www.example.co.uk/category/000000000k/0000";

$pos = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $pos = strpos($url, "/", $pos);
    if (FALSE === $pos) {
        // error
        break;
    }
    $pos++;
}

if ($pos) {
    $url_tmp = substr($url, $pos);
    $url_tmp = str_replace("k/", "x/", $url_tmp);
    $url = substr($url, 0, $pos).$url_tmp;
} else {
    // $pos is 0 or FALSE
    // error
}
```

If url source is not reliable, more checks may be needed.

Comment: This is the solution I went with as it was the one I spent the most time on before coming here. My problem was that I couldn't figure out correct usage of the second param in `preg_replace()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "https://www.example.co.uk/category/000000000k/0000";
echo preg_replace("/^[^k]+k[^k]+\Kk/", "x", $url),"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.example.co.uk/category/000000000x/0000
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               # regex delimiter
  ^             # beginning of line
    [^k]+       # 1 or more any character that is not k
    k           # 1rst letter k
    [^k]+       # 1 or more any character that is not k
    \K          # forget all we have seen until this position
    k           # 2nd letter k
/               # regex delimiter
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution and you've introduced me to the `\K` character.